# Python module added to sys.modules twice with 2 distinct names due to nested paths in sys.path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, sys.path

I ran into some unexpected behaviour in the Python (3.7) import system.
The original issue was caused by my IDE's testing machinery, which adds a bunch of paths to sys.path prior to running test suite.

I isolated the issue, which seems to be caused by (1) having 2 paths in sys.path, one of which is a sub-path of the other; and (2) import statements that use the 2 different paths.
The result is 2 distinct modules in sys.modules for the same concrete package (and all the fun you might imagine that ensues in code using this (these) module(s).

Here is a repl that illustrates a minimal example of the behaviour:  https://repl.it/@powderflask/import-test

The offending code can be boiled down to this (with implied package structure in place):

```
import os,sys

path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.append(path)
sys.path.append(os.path.join(path, 'src'))  # nested path

from src.project.package import a_class
a = a_class.A()

from project.package import a_class
b = a_class.A()

assert a.__class__ != b.__class__
```

I was interested to know if this is a feature (by-design), a bug, or other, but couldn't find documentation that discusses it as a potential.  Anyone have any ideas or can point me to documentation that explains this behaviour?

P.S. in my original code this manifested badly due to a relative import that mapped to one path and an absolute import elsewhere that mapped to a different path; thanks to paths inserted in sys.path by my IDE.  Quite *interesting* to track down.

Comment: I ran into the same problem on the other day... And took me a whole day to track down this issue. Did you find documentation that explains this behavior?

Comment: Found this  [documentation](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-double-import-trap)

Comment: Yes.  Some folks on #python irc helped me see what was happening.  Root issue for me was my IDE doing an import from it's "project root" during unit testing.  I was importing same module from package root.  Thus a relative import in the package was getting imported twice with 2 different paths.   I hope to write an answer to this for posterity when I get a moment.   Thanks for the doc link.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation @steve sent, observations from other SO questions and my own trials, I found out that the cause of double import is adding `__file__` to the sys.path where `os.path.join(__file__, os.pardir)` should be added (one parent directory).

So, instead of

```
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

path should be

```
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__, os.pardir)))
```

This line can be removed too

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(path, 'src'))
```

And then trying access from top-level package was the working solution for me.